# SSRS Groups, Aggregated Group after detailed ones

Tags: reporting-services

in SSRS, I try to create a group structure as in the example below (months have only 5 days here for simplicity). The tricky issue is the last column "Sales(monthly)": It should be a Row Group, grouping by month, *after* the more detailed columns "Day" and "Sales(daily)". It would be no problem to have this column as the second one between "Month" and "Day" column.

But after being already on the "detail level" with "Day" and "Sales(daily)", I cannot create another more aggregated group. And if I just set Group Properties, Group On to Month for the 4th column, then "Day" and "Sales(daily)" also appear aggregated with only 1 row per month.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Or is this just not possible in SSRS?

```
Month  Day   Sales(daily)  Sales(monthly)
Feb    1     100           615
       2     150
       3     130    
       4     125    
       5     110    
March  1     100           685
       2     150    
       3     200    
       4     125    
       5     110    
April  1     100           560
       2     150    
       3     75 
       4     125    
       5     110
```

Many thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a native way to do this in SSRS.

You would need use **LookupSet** to get the daily sales for the month and then use a custom function (**SumLookup**) to get the total.

Then you need to use an IIF so that you only display it on DAY 1.

```
=IIF(Fields!DAY.VALUE <> 1, NOTHING, 
Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!MONTH.Value, Fields!MONTH.Value, Fields!SALES.Value, "Dataset1")))
```

Function code:

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal

If items Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()

suma = 0
ct = 0

For Each item As Object In items

  suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
  ct += 1

Next

If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 

End Function
```

**SSRS**:

> Use LookupSet to retrieve a set of values from the specified dataset
>   for a name-value pair where there is a 1-to-many relationship. For
>   example, for a customer identifier in a table, you can use LookupSet
>   to retrieve all the associated phone numbers for that customer from a
>   dataset that is not bound to the data region.

Comment: Hannover Fist, thank you. Calculating the values shouldn't be the problem, comes from a SSAS cube. Displaying it in grouped (merged) rows is. This would be a solution to accept the non-grouped rows (and try to hide this fact by having no border lines within), but to put the value only into the first row. Mike

Comment: The IIF statement (`IIF(Fields!DAY.VALUE <> 1, NOTHING, ...`) should only display the value on day 1 of each month.