# SSRS LOOKUP with row grouping

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to add a column to tablix that uses different dataset. Now the **dataset1** holds new data and **dataset2** holds old comparison data.

The tablix is using **dataset1** and the row in question is grouped by D_ID now I added a column that needs to binded with D_ID(dataset1) to D_ID(dataset2)

```
=-1*sum(Lookup(Fields!D_ID.Value, Fields!D_ID.Value, Fields!BUD_OLD.Value, "OLD")+Lookup(Fields!D_ID.Value, Fields!D_ID.Value, Fields!ACK_BUD_OLD.Value, "OLD"))
```

However this does take into account that what I need is all the rows from BUD_OLD with D_ID = smth to be summed together. The lookup only returns one value not a sum of all values with D_ID.

Example

```
D_ID        SUM(BUD_NEW+ACK_BUD_NEW)           SUM(BUD_OLD+ACK_BUD_OLD)         
**100**           **75**  (40+35)                    **15**(SHOULD BE 15+20=35)
```

How can I get the sum?

Comment: Share a sample of both datasets in order to recreate your scenario.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta - c'mon Al, we don't need no sticking data.

Comment: @HannoverFist, maybe you're right, but most users don't know what is possible with their data, it often happens that you provide an answer based on a vague data description, then the OP comes again saying it doesn't work since data is not structured as you thought.

Answer (score 2):

**LOOKUP** only gets a single value.

You would need to use LOOKUPSET and a special function to **SUM** the results.

Luckily, this has been done before.

[SSRS Groups, Aggregated Group after detailed ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482102/ssrs-groups-aggregated-group-after-detailed-ones)

From BIDS:

> **LOOKUP**: Use Lookup to retrieve the value from the specified dataset for a name-value pair where there is a 1-to-1 relationship.
>   For example, for an ID field in a table, you can use Lookup to
>   retrieve the corresponding Name field from a dataset that is not bound
>   to the data region.
>
> **LOOKUPSET**: Use LookupSet to **retrieve a set of values** from the specified dataset for a name-value pair where there is a 1-to-many
>   relationship. For example, for a customer identifier in a table, you
>   can use LookupSet to retrieve all the associated phone numbers for
>   that customer from a dataset that is not bound to the data region.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression requires a second "sum"

Try the following:

-1*sum(Lookup(Fields!D_ID.Value, Fields!D_ID.Value, Fields!BUD_OLD.Value, "OLD")+SUM(Lookup(Fields!D_ID.Value, Fields!D_ID.Value, Fields!ACK_BUD_OLD.Value, "OLD")